# Beautifulsoup no img

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm trying to code up a script in python 2.7 using bs4 to scrape the images and rename the files to my server and display it in a low bandwidth friendly manner, and update it on cronjobs every 3hrs by overwriting the existing images.

The problem in my code is nothing turns up not even a error.

Here's the actual code:

```
import requests
import random
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def download_web_image(url):
    name = random.randrange(1, 1000)
    full_name = str(name) + "psdata.gif"
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, full_name)

timecapture = (0, 24, 48, 72)

for time in timecapture:
    url = 'http://www.weatheronline.co.uk/marine/weather?LEVEL=4&LANG=en&TIME=' + str(time) + '&CEL=C&SI=mph&MN=gfs&MODELLTYP=pslv&WIND=g205'
    source_code = requests.get(url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
    for link in soup.find('img', src=True):
        href = 'http://www.weatheronline.co.uk' + link.get('href')
        download_web_image(href)
```

The data from the webpage is in between this tag:

```
<div class="zent">
    <img usemap="#karte" class="eMap" id="pictureid" src="/daten/sailcharts/gfs/2015/03/11/pslv_poly_06-2015031018.gif" border="0" alt="We 11.03.2015 06 UTC" width="634" height="490">
</div>
```

Comment: try: `[link.get('href') for link in soup.select('#pictureid')]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the pictures by `id`. To join URL parts, use [`urlparse.urljoin()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urljoin):

```
base_url = 'http://www.weatheronline.co.uk'
print urljoin(base_url, soup.find('img', id='pictureid')['src'])
```

Answer (score 0):

This below will give you the links to any 'img' with 'src':

```
samplehtml="""
<div class="zent">
    <img usemap="#karte" class="eMap" id="pictureid" src="/daten/sailcharts/gfs/2015/03/11/pslv_poly_06-2015031018.gif" border="0" alt="We 11.03.2015 06 UTC" width="634" height="490">
    <img usemap="#karte" class="eMap" id="pictureid" src="/daten/sailcharts/gfs/2015/03/11/pslv_poly_06-2015031018.gif" border="0" alt="We 11.03.2015 06 UTC" width="634" height="490">
</div>
"""

baseurl = 'http://www.weatheronline.co.uk'

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
imglinks = [baseurl+x['src'] for x in BeautifulSoup(samplehtml).find_all('img',src=True)]
print imglinks
```

Out:

```
[u'http://www.weatheronline.co.uk/daten/sailcharts/gfs/2015/03/11/pslv_poly_06-2015031018.gif',
u'http://www.weatheronline.co.uk/daten/sailcharts/gfs/2015/03/11/pslv_poly_06-2015031018.gif']
```